# Sylius - Editable Product Code (SKU)

Tags: sylius

I need to implement an SKU code for products, I was just wondering has anybody any thought on the best way to do this.  The SKU needs to be editable after creation.

I feel I have a couple of ways:

1. (Idealy) I would like to use Product.Code, but this is not an editable field after product creation.  I would seem I need to override the ProductType#buildForm class/method to not use AddCodeFormSubscriber(). Although I can't seem to figure out how to get the system to use a different form.
2. Add SKU to the model of Product and figure out how to add it to the ProductType form and again try and figure out how to use a different form.

I am open to suggestions on how to do it the right way.

*Would any of the Sylius developers care to elaborate why they decided to make the Code field un-editable?*

Comment: Either way you need to override the form, so option 2 seems the best. There is a page on overriding forms in the documentation - http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/form.html. You may need to override both variant and product, but maybe just one. I haven't checked out the code for a while

Answer (score 0):

If you want use product code as editable field in Sylius Beta.1, you can create ProductType extension to current product type and add your custom subscriber which will make code field editable. I did this in my bundle and it works:

create subscriber class wchich will change disabled state to false:

```
namespace App\Bundle\Form\EventListener;

/* add required namespaces */

/**
 * Custom code subscriber
 */
class CustomCodeFormSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    private $type;
    private $label;

    /**
     * @param string $type
     * @param string $label
     */
    public function __construct($type = TextType::class, $label = 'sylius.ui.code')
    {
        $this->type  = $type;
        $this->label = $label;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $disabled = false;

        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->add('code', $this->type, ['label' => $this->label, 'disabled' => $disabled]);
    }

}
```

create form extension and use custom subscriber:

```
namespace App\Bundle\Form\Extension;

use App\Bundle\Form\EventListener\CustomCodeFormSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductType;

/* use other required namespaces etc */

/**
 * Extended Product form type
 */
class ProductTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        /* custom stuff for ur form */
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new CustomCodeFormSubscriber());
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return ProductType::class;
    }
}
```

register your form extension as a service:

```
app.form.extension.type.product:
    class: App\Bundle\Form\Extension\ProductTypeExtension
    tags:
        - { name: form.type_extension, priority: -1, extended_type: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductType }
```